# Side navigation menu like Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, navigation, android-side-navigation

I'm looking for something similar to what the new Facebook app has implemented for the Android/ios mobile applications. I am referring to a side navigation menu which opens with a finger movement. Something like [this](http://venturebeat.com/2011/12/07/facebook-for-android-upgraded-with-better-navigation-faster-photo-views/)

Is there any library or example where I can check?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just refer following question in SOF

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide/8673805#8673805

Comment: This has been answered already by Aruna Lakmai in the comment above and should be marked as answered. Basically he links to the previous duplicate Stack Overflow question which has some great answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide/8673805#8673805

Answer (score 6):

Use SideNavigationView for side menu like facebook. But you will need a library for this which you can download from here **"https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation".**

Code for using it is:

```
SideNavigationView  sideNavigationView;
sideNavigationView = (SideNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.side_navigation_view);
sideNavigationView.setMenuItems(R.menu.sliding);
sideNavigationView.toggleMenu();
```

Now, make menu you want to show in Slide menu.

All the best....

Answer (score 5):

Like Wubao Li said , this now is supported by android in the DrawerLayout

Here is a tutorial of how to use it 
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

And here a doc about how it should work 
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 3):

With android support package revision 13( may 2013), there is DrawerLayout for creating a Navigation Drawer that can be pulled in from the edge of a window. And, navigation drawer is a design pattern now. http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 2):

This is my implemetnation
https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/Swiper
Enjoy :)