# Make Slide Through in Fragment (Like Facebook) for different Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have got an example of Fragment but i want different activities to be shown on Right side.

[image] [image]

This is something like Sliding the image.

I want to show different activities on Right side when "Home", "Post", "Live" options are selected. Other work is done of sliding and all, i have major problem in selection different options.

Any Help will be Appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Maybe it was already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide

Comment: @JoãoLopes : Thank You i had gone through it...