# How to show menu items in a form the Facebook showing its lists?

Tags: android, facebook, dialog, android-actionbar

I need to create a function something that Facebook has been done in its application.
In my application, i have header bar (not really action bar) at top of my screen. in left corner of it, i have an image which acts as menu (Also Facebook has this button).
I want when user clicks on it, new window appears and covers half of screen and below activity shifts to right of it.

is there any resource for this behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the solution in this question on SO: [Android Facebook style slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide).

Look at these answers here:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768498/450534
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673805/450534