# Android java 2.3.3, how to create a menu like steam?

Tags: java, android, layout, menu, android-sdk-2.3

How do you make a steam like menu?
Below is a screenshot from my Samsung Galaxy S. The menu unfolds when you press the menu button on the bottom of the phone and it pushes the current window to the side and displays the menu. So it steals 70% of the screen. Question is, how is it built? I don't even know where to start building something like this. Any ideas? Tutorials?

Should be compliant with android 2.3.3.

[image: Screenshot from my Samsung Galaxy S]

Comment: there are many solutions provided in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jeremy Feinstein's [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library. It works very well and actually performs smoother than the Steam implementation of it.