# Android library for menu

Tags: android, android-side-navigation

I really love the new menus in the Android apps Spotify, YouTube, Google+ etc. And I would like to implement it in my apps.
Is there a library or another solution to include it in an Android java project?

Comment: When you say menues you refer to? There is more than 1 menu in android.

Comment: It's called facebook like menu ^_^ It's popular nowadays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide/8673805

Answer (score 0):

It's not official, but side navigation seems to be the prevailing term:

> Side navigation is a [UI pattern](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html) that provides users quick
>   shortcuts to the most important part of the application without having
>   to leave the screen they are on.

[image]