# Vertical Action Bar for Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to display the Action Bar Vertically in my App.
I have found few examples for the Horizontal One, but not any for the Vertical One.

Can anyone please give me any example for the Vertical Action Bar.

Thanks,
David Brown

Comment: Are you referring to something like this (illustrated on the right). http://www.netbooknews.com/wp-content/2011/09/android-fragments.jpg

Comment: vertical bar is not yet provided,,it shows errors...

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the [Android UI design](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) guide about a vertical [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html).  But you might be able to coerce a similar effect by locking the display orientation, and then applying a [rotation to the View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation) in the content area.  You also might be able to get somewhere by downloading the source code for [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and implementing your own version of the ActionBar.  But I don't recommend either of these solutions.  If you're really that intent on putting actions on the side of your screen, I suggest either a small vertical LinearLayout, or implement one of the side navigation solutions as discussed in [Android Facebook style slide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8657894/517561).