# How to implement "SplitView" on Android phone (not tabled) like new YouTube app?

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to implement "SplitView" on Android phone (not tabled) like new YouTube app.

[image: Youtube app splitview]

Any ideas how do it?

Comment: A similar question was asked here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide.  Unfortunately, it's not part of the standard library, and you have to recreate it by hand.  There's an example using a HorizontalScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a specific programming question. More like an open question. Anyways you can start by researching `Fragments`.  Here is a link to a tutorial: [Fragments](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2448-how-to-use-the-fragment-class-in-the-android-honeycomb-sdk-preview/).

Hope that helps.