# How to create facebook like side menu in my activity?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android facebook style slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide)

I have a Image Button. On tapping on Image Button I want to create side menu just like Facebook. In Facebook when we tap on Notification or message there is a side menu. similar menu I want to make in our application. Please help me and send me code also if available.

Answer (score 2):

Here is interesting article, which discuss *Slide Navigation* pattern [Emerging UI Pattern - Side Navigation](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html). It contain a lot of links to other discussions as well as links to existing libraries which help to implement *Side Navigation* pattern.