# Image Reposition Like Facebook Cover In Android

Tags: java, android

I want to implement image reposition like facebook cover in my android app. Actually I don't have any background to do this. How can I start it?

Comment: i think sliding drawer/menu will help you. https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu & https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo & http://stackoverflow.com/q/8657894/582571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a **graphics** thing, check out `opengl`.  If its swipe thing check out viewpager.  Most likely you have to use a `SurfaceView`, some transparency and then draw the image onto the surface view as needed.