# Android: How to implement the way how facebook application left menu when sliding with a gesture

Tags: android, facebook, menu, youtube

I saw the facebook and youtube application on Android has a left menu showing up when you sliding it across.

Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: use frame layout and hide it or unhide it based on the click event

Comment: You will find what you need [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide) . The link to a sample project is [here](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android facebook style slide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide)

Answer (score 0):

use feinstein slide menu it is a very good option.https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu