# What controls should I use for this android UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, components

I'm developing an android application, one page is like this:

[image]

You can see on the top of right part, there is a "settings" button. When clicking it, there will be a panel  come out from the left.

I'm new to android, and I don't know what components shall I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `side navigation` or a `sliding menu`. Introduced by facebook i believe.

Here is an answer how to design this:

[Android Facebook style slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide/8673805#8673805)

and project code:

https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo

I haven't just searched for it and pasted the link here, i actually did this in my application, it is easy to implement and works great

Comment: `android-sliding-menu-demo` is pretty easy to use

Answer (score 0):

You can use SlidingDrawer as below:

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/my_sliding_drawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/handle">
        <!-- Your handle content comes here. -->
    </ImageButton>    

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content">
        <!-- Your drawer contents come here. -->
    </LinearLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>
```