# iPhone / How to create a facebook-like application?

Tags: iphone, facebook, menu, facebook-like

I want to create a Facebook-like application, with a menu like this : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCyzF.png

**Is there a simple solution with iOS 6 SDK ?** 
*PS.: it would be only for iPhone (not iPad), and I don't need a search-bar.*

Thank you,

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide/8673805#8673805

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ZUUIRevealController. [Here](https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController) is the link of GitHub and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDYHFMYoDcU) is a simple tutorial on Youtube.