# Android side navigation menu : how to include the actionbar in the slided view?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I want to add a side navigation menu to my android app (like Facebook, Google+, Spotify, Prixing, Evernote, etc)

I already had a look here : [Android Facebook style slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide/8673805)
and here : https://github.com/Gregadeaux/android-fly-in-app-navigation

By following this last link, I got a working implementation which I customized a bit.

[image]

As you can see the action bar doesn't slide. That's normal since it's not a part of the sliding view in the Gregadeaux's implementation.

I'd like to include the actionbar in the sliding view. It's probably possible by making a custom implementation of the actionbar but I'd like to keep the original one.

The Google+ app seems not to use a custom actionbar.

[image]

Any idea how I can do that? Thanks :)

EDIT: After some search I eventually found that the Google+ app is using a custom actionbar implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a even better solution! super easy to use, super flexible.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

EDIT:

Note that the new navigation drawer should now be used in order to comply to the android design guidelines. Check http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 2):

It was answered in the same question. The answer says "This one also slides the action bar away!". [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532163/1068546) [Blog Post](http://www.coboltforge.com/2012/07/tech-stuff-a-sliding-menu-for-android-very-much-like-the-google-and-facebook-apps-have-it/)