# How to place an ActionBar on a SlidingMenu ( like in the Evernote app)?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

[image]

I want to make slide menu that has ActionBar like in Evernote. In this app, Seem like it has 2 ActionBars(I'm not sure about it). One at main and another one is in the sliding menu.

**Is there anyway to build 2 ActionBars like this?** Or it's just a layout arrangement to resemble ActionBar look.

Thank for all your help and sorry for my english.

ps. I use ActionBarSherlock and SlidingMenu to achieve this, but I can't find the way to do it like in Evernote.

Comment: AFAIK you probably want to draw that your self ( the 2nd look-a-like actionbar)

Comment: Hmm seems like I have run into the same problem....I have implemented the actionbar on the sliding menu however I cant seem to add the action bar on the behind menu.

Comment: @Sizer can u help me to make this type of menu. i am using Jeremy Feinstein's SlidingMenu library. but i am not able to do this. can u give me Full example of this sliding menu??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to do it with the help of Gunnar Karlsson who pushed me in the right direction Instead of a SearchView

I implemented an ImageButton like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#333333" >

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:onClick="showPopup" />

</LinearLayout>


<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/list"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in the my mainActivity I simply pulled this from the google sample code for creating a pop up menu:

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

And it worked. Thank you Gunnar Karlsson.

Answer (score 9):

You wrote:

> I use (...) SlidingMenu

If by `SlidingMenu` you mean [Jeremy Feinstein](https://github.com/jfeinstein10)'s [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), and you want to keep using this menu library, you can't use a 'real' `ActionBar`, since `SlidingMenu's` menu is implemented as a `Fragment`, named `SlidingMenuFragment` in the library. A `Fragment` can't hold an `ActionBar`.

You can create a layout which looks like an `ActionBar`. In `SlidingMenuFragment's` you set the layout file like so:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_menu,null);
```

In the menu's layout file, here called `sliding_menu.xml`, you can for example make a `SearchView` look like it's in an `ActionBar` by nesting it in a layout at the top. You then set that layout's background color/drawable to something different from the rest of the list. See below example (I'm aware nesting LinearLayouts isn't pretty...Just a quick example that uses the `LinearLayout` from the `SlidingMenu` example app to get the idea across):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#333333" >

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will look like:

[image]

when open, where the light grey box to the right is part of the 'real' `ActionBar`.

*Edit:* You wrote in a comment:

> The searchView example works Im having trouble getting a drop down menu to work in the same way.

The drop-down menu in the EverNote app looks like it's been implemented with a Holo-themed [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html). Android Developers has a thorough [introduction](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) on how to add a `Spinner` to a layout. The Spinner's logic/java code would be placed in `SlidingMenuFragment` (if you go with the `SlidingMenu` library).

Comment: Can you recommend any other libraries Im not stuck with using SlidingMenu in particular, I just found it to be the best one.

Comment: I've tested all libraries at this link as of Aug 2012: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide/9905415#9905415 for an app I worked on. Feinstein's SlidingMenu library was the only one I managed to implement, where the client requirements were 1) ActionBar-like search bar on menu 2) the ActionBar slides to right when menu opens and 3) all views are Fragments. So, net, I can't (because they didn't work for me...) recommend another library but do have a look at that list.

Comment: OK thanks for the help, Im trying to implement a menu just as in the evernote app would you have any ideas on how to implement that? The searchView example works Im having trouble getting a drop down menu to work in the same way.

Comment: @Tkingovr I've added an edit to the end of my answer about how to add a drop down menu.

Comment: Got it working with an image button but you definitely deserve the bounty. Thanks for the time and effort to help out. Really appreciated.