# Blackberry facebook style slide

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I like to implement a similar implementation from the URL ([Android Facebook style slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide)) for blackberry 6 devices. Please suggest me samples/architecture for getting this implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I got this worked,

Used Two Vertical Field Managers, within One Horizontal Field Manager. Using Timer updated the left Menu Holding VFM's width for collapse and open events, also adjusted the xpos of child fields.