# How to re-size fragment and set to Google Map V2?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am trying to create `Facebook` like `slider` from the following [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14117674/1278196), where i want to change map width at a run time.

I tried inside bindComponent method , but its not working for me..

### **map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

### Activity

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
     OnClickListener {


private ImageView mSlider;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mapViewParameters;
GoogleMap gMap;
SupportMapFragment supportMap;
private DisplayMetrics metrics;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slider);

    bindComponents();

}



private void bindComponents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    supportMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);

    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    mapViewParameters = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(
            R.id.mapView).getLayoutParams();
    mapViewParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
    findViewById(R.id.mapView).setLayoutParams(mapViewParameters);

    // Map
    gMap = supportMap.getMap();
    gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    mSlider = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.msliderImage);




}
  }
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: According to me issue is related to bindComponents() where map's width is resized

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you check [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library. I think it's best i ever seen in web for implementing Facebook like Sliding Menu

Comment: @Mitesh Agrawal yes i am....and my answer is the same. Component you using is defenately NOT the best one so i recomend you to change it.