# Two level Sliding menu in android application

Tags: android

I want to use facebook like sliding menu, but with a menu and submenu. If any item in the menu is clicked a sub menu must appear and both the parent menu and the sub menu must be displayed. Is there any library available for this that could be used even for APIs below 16. I have searched a lot for implementing submenus, but not successful. Pls help...

Comment: Are you looking for facebook type sliding menu??

Comment: yes. facebook type sliding menu for phones supporting API 7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide

Comment: I want something like this. Sub menu must appear on clicking parent menu item and it should push main screen
[link](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&tbo=d&biw=1366&bih=587&tbm=isch&tbnid=hd9JJqHxd_gb8M:&imgrefurl=http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1071581911000772&docid=lVBVm_exw3r1AM&imgurl=http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S1071581911000772-gr1.jpg&w=390&h=198&ei=NoMbUfvsCI3irAekh4GoCA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=73&vpy=237&dur=15854&hovh=158&hovw=312&tx=233&ty=109&sig=108603685564544376050&page=2&tbnh=131&tbnw=259&start=19&ndsp=27&ved=1t:429,r:27,s:0,i:169)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear to me. But with what I feel is use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and define both left fragment and right fragment in xml and use refer it in the MainActivity. 
I hope I helped. Is this what you want?

Comment: I want to use it for an app using API 7 and above but ActionBarSherlock can only be used above API 16.

Comment: ActionBar can be used above API level 11 (Ref. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) and ActionBarSherlock can be used much much below that. So please check :)

Comment: I have confused the menu with the actionbar so i have updated my question. Sorry... Thanks for the help and could you help me with this menu and submenu thing?

Comment: Hi, I have the same requirement. Cold you help out if you have got the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @jasdmystery No i havent :(