# Blackberry 10 Left Slider

Tags: blackberry-10

The menu slider that the menu is popping out from the left side of the screen is awesome. 
"I was just trying to see how it can be emulated in my application.

Any one has a clue how it can be achieved?"

I want it to look exactly like on the picture, with menu items on the left.

[image: Left Menu Slider]

There is a similar Android [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TabbedPane](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__tabbedpane.html) for that purpose, having left menu populated with set of [Actions](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__actionitem.html). However, usage of `TabbedPane` means you have to use [Tabs](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__tab.html).

In your case, you'll most likely have to use `Actions` menu which pops out from the *right* side as this complies with [Blackberry Design Guidelines](https://developer.blackberry.com/design/bb10/) and fits your goals as I can see it from the screenshot provided better.

Comment: Outstanding! This is exactly what was I looking for! Thanks Sir!