# Slide a navigation pane to the right and move a ListView from Left

Tags: c++, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

In the image below, imagine the Menu I have implemented as a ListView.
On the right hand side (the dialog which slides to the right, for the menu to show), I have a *NavigationPane*.

I learned how to slide pages if I have two containers in one page for example.
But is it possible to create animation using the NavigationPane and ListView as I mentioned
above (e.g., slide the NavigationPane to the right, so that the ListView comes out from the left)?.
If yes, how? Any code samples?. I may need to do it all in C++.

[image]

Comment: Why not use the action overflow for these actions instead?

Comment: I answered to similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274503/blackberry-10-left-slider/15351632#15351632 Check it out.

Comment: Hi, thanks but that is not exactly what I want. In your suggestion you recommend to use either TabbedPane or Action Bars, in my case, I need to add a searchbar on top of menu items, that is why I can't use TabbedPane and Action Bars, and need to implement the menu (as shown above, although without the searchbar) manually as a ListView for example. The right dialog I want to be a NavigationPane. Now my problem is I don't know how to enable sliding - i.e., that NavigationPane moves to the right when some button is clicked on it, and menu slides out of the left.

Comment: Maybe you should start using a bb10 design instead of losing so much time for reimplementing a similar feature.
If you still want it, I don't think you can slide the navPane, but you can add content with negative padding and a translation left/right to make it visible