# How to create MenuDrawer like Hangouts apps?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingdrawer

I would like to implement a drawer in my app, like in the hangouts app, just on the left side, but thats not the most importent, its good on the right too.
I already implemented a menu drawer, how can i make it semi closed like the picture on the link?

Or is this a new kind of drawer? Then whats its name? So i can search for some samples.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxdbO.png

I used `support.v4` library, and the `actionbarsherlock`. So this project is api >=10.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: hey... check out these awesome [answers..](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8657894/2219600)They may help .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [`SlidingPaneLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html). In this week's episode of Android Design in Action, Roman Nurik also [mentioned](http://youtu.be/JrxQIs0GmzM?t=12m43s) that it is used by the Hangouts app.

Watch [this part](http://youtu.be/Jl3-lzlzOJI?t=16m22s) of the Google I/O Session *Android Design for UI Developers* to see how to implement this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean about `SlidingDrawer` to the left, but I'll guess that you refer to the `SlidingMenu`, am I correct? In that case, I've used this library successfully:

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

This library is also compatible with the `ActionbarSherlock`.

Comment: @executioner did u visited the slidingMenu page?

Comment: I've seen the picture @executioner, but what should I look after? There is no SlidingMenu at the left?