# How to perform Facebook like activity in android application

Tags: android, facebook, layout

[image]

I want to make activity which is present in Facebook mobile application, 
same as below image

Comment: for that you have make custom layout.

Comment: please suggest me any reference project

Comment: do you want to open sliding menu like facebook??

Comment: yes i want to do but i got project from https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#setup but i cant able to open include library in eclipse

Comment: But when you have import the project in eclipse then copy that project to worlspace??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Facebook style slide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the Android `Navigation Drawer`? It is referenced [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) on the Android developer site. Implementation doc is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do facebook like side navigation then use the following library
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: but how to add library in eclipse

Comment: see this link http://boroniatechnologies.com/installing-slidingmenu-android-library-and-example/

Answer (score 0):

Use the DrawerLayout APIs available in the Support Library.
For more information click [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)