# Sliding Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, slidingdrawer, slidingmenu

I want to put settings in left side of screen.

There will be switcher, listviews and textviews.

In result I need like this example:

[image]        [image]

Is it possible and how I can start with?

Comment: use [Navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: Sorry for bad screenshots, it was animation and I just changed it on two screenshots.

Comment: Do Navigation Drawer allows to use myLayout? I don't need ListLayout like in Menu.

Comment: you want to add customized layout.

Comment: Yes, I want to add customized layout.

Comment: refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide).me also do one app like that what you expect(that link only help me to do that thing easily).

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Sliding Menu Library** to give such effect...

You can get the code from [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

You can also refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680985/a-library-for-a-sliding-up-drawer-similar-to-new-google-music-and-rdio).

Comment: Can I use not only list layout there?

Comment: @p.Valery Ya sure... U can create any xml file and use that

Comment: Whatever layout you want, you can just create xml file for that

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, and you can implement it using the [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) which comes with android support library.

Comment: I must use support-library-v4 or higher?

Comment: v4 - Which means that your applications can use the libraries' features and still be compatible with devices running Android 1.6 (API level 4) and up.

Answer (score 0):

You must check out the [`Ribbon Menu`](https://github.com/jaredsburrows/RibbonMenu)

**1) What's the Purpose**

Ease of Access: Allow easy access to a menu that slides in and out
Ease of Implementation: Update the same screen using minimal amount of code
Independency: Does not require support libraries such as ActionBarSherlock
Customization: Easy to change colors and menus

**2)What's New**

Changed the sliding animation to match Facebook and Google+ apps
Added standard ActionBar (you can chose to use ActionBarSherlock)
Used menuitem to open the Menu
Added ability to update ListView on main Activity
Added 2 ListViews to the Menu, similiar to Facebook and Google+ apps
Added a AutoCompleteTextView and a Button as well to show examples of implemenation
Added method to allow users to hit the 'back button' to hide the menu when it is open
Allows users to interact with background(main ListView) and the menu at the same time unlike the Facebook and Google+ apps!

**OR**

You can also try out with [Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Comment: I don't need exactly Menu, I need just swipping Layout with my Views.
Is it possible to do with RibbonMenu?

Comment: Yes you can swipe your layout with the views on swipe. Its possible with RibbonMenu. And easy to use even.

Comment: Are there some sample or documentation for RibbonMenu?

Comment: You can check out the Demo like i have already provided you which contains a sample demo of RibbonMenu.

Comment: Can you give me a link?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one library file slider.jar into your project and follow this example for the same :
http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Facebook-Style-Slide-Menu-In-Android