# Sliding panel layout with 3 fragments

Tags: android

I want to implement sliding panel layout with left to right and right to left menus. Can I implement with `android.support.v4.slidingpanelayout`.

Comment: You should go to this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide/14117674#14117674). Here you find what you want. thnx

Comment: I saw this link. But there it is only one menu in the left side

Answer (score 0):

Hey check out this [link](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu).It is called reside menu used in Ios.This library has two menus on the left and right as you wanted.