# I want to make activity smaller when open the side bar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, sidebar

When i open the side bar my back activity should get smaller in size how can i implement this ?
[image]

Comment: Go for navigation drawer : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Several libraries are available to get your task.
 read this link: [Slide menu][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide

Comment: @RIT  in that demos background activity not having smaller size it just opens drawer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can also give best effect for smaller activity . Check [ResideMenu](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu)

demo with library. It is perfect for your answer